# OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Why and where I went wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am working on a chat app using sockets in python3 and I have two files server.py and client.py and when I run server.py it runs perfectly fine but when I try to connect to server.py using client.py it returns following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 24, in <module>
    read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

and I did a bit of research and tried things like changing some stuff but that also failed.

Code for both the files:
server.py :

```py
# Imports and initialization

import socket
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
import sys
import threading

init()

quit_msg = '!quit'
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Checking arguments and further code

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print(Fore.RED + "[*] Correct usage: script, IP address(host), port number(room)")
    sys.exit()

host = str(sys.argv[1])
port = int(sys.argv[2])

server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

list_of_clients = []

def client_thread(conn , addr):
    print(Fore.GREEN + "[+] Welcome to this room")
    while True:
        try:
            message = conn.recv(2048)
            if message:
                print(Fore.YELLOW + f"[{addr[0]}" + Fore.GREEN + f"{message}")
                message_to_send = Fore.YELLOW + f"[{addr[0]}" + Fore.GREEN + f"{message}"
                brodcast(message_to_send, conn)
            else:
                remove(conn)
        except:
            continue

def brodcast(message, connection):
    for clients in list_of_clients:
        if clients != connection:
            try:
                clients.send(message)
            except:
                clients.close()
                remove(clients)

def remove(connection):
    if connection in list_of_clients:
        list_of_clients.remove(connection)

while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    list_of_clients.append(conn)
    print(Fore.CYAN + f"[ {addr} ] connected")
    thread = threading.Thread(target=client_thread, args=(conn, addr))

conn.close()
server.close()
```

client.py:

```py
# Imports and intilization

import socket
import sys
import select
from colorama import init, Fore, Style

init()

quit_msg = '!quit'
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print(Fore.RED + "[*] Correct usage: script, IP address(host), port number(room)")
    sys.exit()

host = str(sys.argv[1])
port = int(sys.argv[2])

client.connect((host, port))

while True:
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, client]
    read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
    for socks in read_sockets:
        if socks == client:
            message = socks.recv
            print(message)
        else:
            message = sys.stdin.readline()
            client.send(message)
            sys.stdout.write("<You>")
            sys.stdout.write(message)
            sys.stdout.flush()

client.close()
```

Commands:
In terminal 1:

```
python3 server.py 127.0.0.1 8080
```

Output after running command in terminal 1:
`nothing`
In terminal 2:

```
python3 client.py 127.0.0.1 8080
```

Output after running command in terminal 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 24, in <module>
    read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

And I also noticed one thing that after running command in terminal 2 it exits with an error but in terminal 1 it returns:

```
[ ('127.0.0.1', 10703) ] connected
```

So, this is all the information related to my question so please solve my problem and explain where I have done things wrong.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) mention what's wrong:

> File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On Windows, the underlying select() function is provided by the WinSock library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate from WinSock.

You can't wait on `stdin` on Windows.